# Jboss 5.1 Session Timeout Not working

Tags: java, servlets, jboss5.x, session-timeout

I am facing the same issue where I am using Jboss 5.1 server and my session timeout doesnt work. I have tried the above steps by setting in deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml . Also i tried by programmatically forcing the timeout using - HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(int seconds) But still it doesnt get timed out.

Please suggest/ help....

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(0)
```

if you set the value to 0 it timesout immediately.

if you want the session to stay idle till 60 minutes then specify in seconds
60*60

```
HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);
```

i think literally u are calling HttpSession.... .the above does not work . try below ,also let me know how you have configured in web.xml(paste the configuration in your question.)

```
request.getSession(false).setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);
```

while you need to specify the runtime parameter while running JBOSS server as below , to do it go to **jboss-5.0.1.GA\server\default\deploy** then edit the xml file named
**properties-service.xml**  and add the following xml snippet .

```
 // Set raw properties file style properties.

<attribute name="Properties">
        org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=false
</attribute>
```

Comment: Hi,I want it to time out after 60 minutes. I have tried the following ways 1. setting in WEB-INF/web.xml  2. deployers/jbossweb.deployer/web.xml   3. programmatically setting as HttpSession.setMaxInactiveInterval(timeout) .. None of the three worked for me. Please  suggest....

Comment: Hi , This is what i did. First i made an entry in web.xml made an entry :-                                                        <session-config> <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>         </session-config> . When that didnt work i tried  :-               HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);                              But this is not helping me.

Comment: Hi , I specified the runtime parameter while running JBOSS server by editing  the xml file named properties-service.xml and added the following xml snippet . <attribute name="Properties">          org.apache.catalina.STRICT_SERVLET_COMPLIANCE=false  </attribute>        But still its not working for me. Session is not getting timed out after 60 mins... I am programatically killing the session by saying session.setMaxInactiveInterval(3600);          Please help.